# how to get all the posts and blog post like portfolio by categories in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, blogs, custom-wordpress-pages

how to get all the posts and blog post like the link by categories in wordpress . please check the link. there are some tabs options as categories and displaying posts.

I want show my all posts by categories like this page. 
http://www.creativemedicalresearch.com/blog/

Comment: You can call an ajax request for each tab and print html content.

Comment: could you please show ,e an example how to do that? as i am not good at ajax. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you be more specific, do you already have some code?

This is how you would print the categories for example:

```
<?php $categories = get_categories(); ?>
<ul class="categories__list">
    <?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>
        <li class="categories__list--item">
            <a href="<?php echo get_category_link($category->cat_ID); ?>">
                <?php echo $category->name; ?>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul> <!--/.categories__list -->
```